# Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php7.0

Tags: debian, php7, add-apt-repository

I'm trying to install Rainloop Webmail on Debian.

I've added the next package

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

This key was added: 4F4EA0AAE5267A6C

```
But upon apt-get update:
Reading package lists... Done   
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

All solutions that I find are removing the repository, but how can I install the libapache2-mod-php7.0 package then?

Thanks!

Comment: Asking a Debian question on AskUbuntu is unlikely to produce a good, Debian answer.

Comment: Well, Ubuntu is a Debian system. On top of that, there is not askdebian.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libapache2-mod-php` is available from the Ubuntu official repository. To install it please run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php
```

The latest version for PHP7+ will be installed.

> **Please, note:**
>
> As of PHP version 7+. You do not need to specify the version of PHP7+ as
>   all PHP related packages will contain just **PHP** in their name with no version
>   specified and will refer to and install version PHP7+