# E: Unable to locate package php7.4-pear

Tags: 18.04, package-management, php

I am trying to install php extension pear for php 7.4 in Ubuntu 18.04. When I run command `sudo apt-get install php7.4-pear` I get this result:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-pear 
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-pear' 
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-pear'
```

How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: There is ___no___ package named `php7.4-pear`: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php7.4-pear&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all Can you try `php-pear`? And please note that Ubuntu 18.04 will be EOL in several months.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php7.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175749/unable-to-locate-package-libapache2-mod-php7-0)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have third party repositories, there's no package named `php7.4-pear`. The correct name would be `php-pear`.